# Se descuadran los inputs en el formulario

Tags: reactjs

Tengo un tipo de select2 que al hacer una busqueda se abre una lista pero en el formulario la lista desplaza los inputs

mi lista esta estructurada de la siguiente manera:

```
<ul id="ulAgencyStyle" className="overflow-auto sticky-top">
                                            {
                                                (()=>{                                                    
                                                    return(
                                                        this.state.dataListAirline.map((object,keyObject) => {
                                                            return(
                                                                <li key={keyObject} value={object.airport_id} onClick={e=> this.handleClick(e, object.description, keyObject)} className="list-group-item list-group-item-action py-0" >{object.description}</li>
                                                            )
                                                        })
                                                    );                                                        
                                                })
                                                ()                                                    
                                            }
                                            </ul>
```

el css es el siguiente:

```
#ulAgencyStyle{
    max-height: 300px !important;
    overflow:scroll !important;
    padding-inline-start: 0px !important;
    position: relative !important;
    border-radius: 15px !important;
}
```

asi se ven normalmente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al hacer una busqueda en airline se desplazan los inputs de abajo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Quedo pendiente y gracias.

Comment: podrias agregar de esto una imagen para clarificar que es lo que pasa?

Comment: agregue imagenes de como se ve y como se desplaza, gracias